# Universal variable for different sizes

Tags: c++

I do some `recv()` and `send()` on sockets and I know the maximum `packetSize` is `256 MB`.

Does it exist some variable which finds out the length of the packet and allocates that space?

I mean

1. when `packetSize` is just `1045 B`, allocate that size
2. when `packetSize` is `56 MB`, allocate that size

Thanks!

Comment: `std::vector<std::byte>`?

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out the size of your packet?

Comment: I have this: `int packetSize = recv(socket, (char*)buffer, 1024, 0);`. But that limits `buffer` to `1024 B`.

Comment: If you know how big the message you are sending is, you send the length of the message before sending the message. Make sure you send the size as a [fixed width integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and make sure both sides agree on [the byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If you don't know how big the message is before you start sending, then how can the receiver?

Comment: @JohnDoe: "*Does it exist some variable which finds out the length of the packet and allocates that space?*" Are you asking to find out the size of a packet that has already been received? Because if it's been received, then memory had to be allocated for it. Admittedly, I don't know anything about this `recv` function you use, but whatever's going on within that function and the system it lives in has to be able to get packets from wherever they came from.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `std::vector`. It can contain an arbitrary number of elements.

> Finds out the length of the packet

Are you sure you did not mean length of the message? Also may depend on what protocol you use.

Assuming a streaming protocol such as TCP, you can't really know until you receive the data. If your vector wasn't big enough, then resize and keep receiving until you have gotten all of it (or until you reach some safety limit to mitigate denial of service attacks).